# How to read Configuration value from lowest level value

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to provide some configuration data for my application so that we have simple settings stored in the source control, but our deployment system will replace the Encryption Key in appsettings.json when it deploys.

For development I still want a general key, but for specific users in their secrets I would like to provide a value that they can be sure will be secure.

I have my configuration files setup like this:

appsettings.json

```
{
  "SystemConfiguration" : {
    "EncryptionKey" :  "weak"
  }
}
```

appsettings.Development.json

```
{
  "SystemConfiguration" : {
    "EncryptionKey" :  "devweak"
  }
}
```

In my user secrets

```
{
  "SystemConfiguration" : {
    "EncryptionKey" :  "this is a secret"
  }
}
```

In my controller construction I'm getting the injected `IConfiguration configuration`.

And then

```
 public SysConfigController(IConfiguration configuration)
 {
     var result = configuration["SystemConfiguration:EncryptionKey"];
 }
```

but the value of result is always "weak" unless the higher level settings files don't contain the value at all (`: null`) doesn't work either.

Is there a way that I can retrieve the lowest level value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems your configuration registrations are wrong. The last registration which contains the specific key will be used.

For example in your `Program.cs` file (assuming you are using ASP.NET Core, otherwise `Startup.cs`'s constructor for ASP.NET Core 1.x) you can override the registrations (or just add the ones you like when you use the default host builder method):

```
public static IWebHostBuilder BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
    new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
        {
            var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;

            config
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                .AddUserSecrets<Startup>()
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .AddCommandLine(args);
        })
        .UseIISIntegration()
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .UseApplicationInsights();
```

In this example the following have been registered

- `.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)`:
  Global configuration file
- `.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)`
  Enviornmentspecific configuration file, i.e. `appsettings.Development.json`
- `.AddUserSecrets<Startup>()`
  The user secrets
- `.AddEnvironmentVariables()`
  Environment variables
- `.AddCommandLine(args);`
  Command line parameters

When looking up for a key, the search happens in reverse order. If its defined as command line parameter, it will override all the other keys and values (from environment variable, user secrets, environment specific and global file).

So put the least important file at the beginning and most important (overriding) one at the end.

In this case if its defined in your user secrets, it will override the `appsettings.Development.json` and `appsettings.json` provided values.

From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#providers)

> Configuration sources are read in the order that their configuration providers are specified at startup. The configuration providers described in this topic are described in alphabetical order, not in the order that your code may arrange them. Order configuration providers in your code to suit your priorities for the underlying configuration sources.
>
> A typical sequence of configuration providers is:
>
> - Files (appsettings.json, appsettings..json, where  is the app's current hosting environment)
> - User secrets (Secret Manager) (in the Development environment only)
> - Environment variables
> - Command-line arguments
>
> It's a common practice to position the Command-line Configuration Provider last in a series of providers to allow command-line arguments to override configuration set by the other providers.

Comment: Thanks, I was just playing with the exact same scenario at home to try to reproduce what was going on at work and it's working correctly. The lowest level detail is winning. I'll have to check again on Monday and see if there is something strange going on.. I know i'm using 2.1 with             return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                   .UseStartup<Startup>();

Comment: With `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)` it should use the user secrets in development mode (if ASPNET_ENVIRONMENT='Development') which is the case when debugging form Visual Studio but not when doing `dotnet run`

Comment: Checked the code, a very early in the project we added an additional `.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{username}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)` and I haven't revisited that. It was causing the problem because it had replaced the CreateDefaultBuilder thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use method `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` in Startup.cs.

Describe your setting property in class and bind it. For example:

```
services.Configure<SystemConfiguration>(options => Configuration.GetSection("SystemConfiguration").Bind(options));

public class SystemConfiguration
{
   public string EncryptionKey{get;set;}
}
```

Then, you can use DI for geting class

```
public class SomeClass
{
   private readonly SystemConfiguration _systemConfiguration{get;set;}
   public SomeClass (IOptions<ConfigExternalService> systemConfiguration)
   {
    _systemConfiguration = systemConfiguration;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i should have mentioned that I attempted this approach, but i still ended up with "Weak" where i should have got "this is a secret"